# Mikrotik SIP trunk routing

Tags: networking, routing, voip, sip, mikrotik

I have a Mikrotik RouterOS v6.36 with my network as follows
(I am a newbie to networking in general and have been able to get stuff working half way. I just don't know what to look for.)

- Router:

  - Ether01: ISP Connection(Internet/WAN)
  - Ether02: SIP Trunk(SIP Trunk - No internet)
  - Ether03: Null
  - Ether04: LAN

I have a PBX server on the LocalLan that needs to connect out via Ether01 to authenticate licenses etc. This works fine with no problem.

I now need to connect Ether02 which is a SIP trunk from our ISP to our PBX server.

I am able to get the Router to mark routes and send them out via Ether02 but I am not able to get that data to respond back through Ether02

Please could somebody give me guidance and let me know what data is required to help troubleshoot this.

Comment: This might be a routing problem in PBX, so just check if the PBX can send packets to the mikrotik ether2 IP.

Comment: Hi Arash, I seem to have found the problem. There seemed to be a confusion on my incoming DSTNAT rules between the two Ether ports.

Comment: Maybe you should delete this question then.

Comment: @chicks He deleting or keeping, I had a problem and with this question apparently the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to specify my DSTNAT rules for each ethernet port, instead of having using generic incoming rule